# Error while installing libuvc

Tags: terminal, cmake, ubuntu-14.04, libusb

An error is occurring when I'm trying to install libuvc.
I'm following instructions on https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc

```
git clone https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc
cd libuvc
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make && sudo make install
```

When following the last step it says

```
fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libusb.h>
```

I've already installed the libusb.

Thanks for helping.

**Update:** The error is gone after updating and upgrading the ubuntu and restarting the PC.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem in two steps :

1. Find the libusb.h file manually if you've successfully installed
   libusb.
2. Paste the file to the "include" folder right under the folder of
   "libuvc-master".

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, the error was occurring because the OS was updated.